# Terminal commands in Automator for Profile Manager maintenance

Tags: terminal, automator, osx-server, high-sierra, profile-manager

I am using macOS Server to manage our iPads and the Profile Manager is constantly having problems requiring me to stop the service and reboot the server. I also clean out the completed and non-completed tasks (this sometimes helps). I would like to use Automator to run a daily task to clear the completed tasks from the database and one to clear the non-completed tasks weekly.

Here is the code I have, can someone help me configure this for Automator?

**Clear completed tasks:**

```
sudo -u _devicemgr psql -U _devicemgr -d devicemgr_v2m0 -h /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/PostgreSQL -c "DELETE FROM library_item_tasks WHERE completed_at IS NOT NULL"
```

**Clear non-completed:**

```
sudo -u _devicemgr psql -U _devicemgr -d devicemgr_v2m0 -h /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/PostgreSQL -c "DELETE FROM library_item_tasks WHERE completed_at IS NULL"
```

Comment: One question per question. I removed the question concerning reindexing, which you can ask it in a separate question. That said, the commands you've shown are `shell` commands, so why use Automator when a `bash` script in Terminal will do?

Comment: I don't know bash script. If anyone can write this up in bash I would be grateful.  I inherited this Mac server and am still learning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google: [bash script how to](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=bash+script+how+to&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8) - A `bash` *script* is nothing more then a plain text file that starts with the appropriate [`shebang`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) and has the *commands* you want to execute, one line at at time. Then made executable with [`chmod`](https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/chmod.1.html) and if not placed in a directory in the [`PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) use `./filename` to execute it.

The `./filename` method requires it in the `PWD` in Terminal, otherwise use the *fully qualified pathname*. Placing it in a directory in the `PATH` is typically easiest to then subsequently execute as needed just by `filename`.

**Example:**

**In Terminal:**

```
touch cleartasks
open cleartasks
```

**Add to opened file:**

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo -u _devicemgr psql -U _devicemgr -d devicemgr_v2m0 -h /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/PostgreSQL -c "DELETE FROM library_item_tasks WHERE completed_at IS NOT NULL"
sudo -u _devicemgr psql -U _devicemgr -d devicemgr_v2m0 -h /Library/Server/ProfileManager/Config/var/PostgreSQL -c "DELETE FROM library_item_tasks WHERE completed_at IS NULL"
```

**Save the file.**

**Back in Terminal, make it executable:**

```
chmod u+x cleartasks
```

**To execute:**

```
./cleartasks
```